# Как сделать на форме выпадающий список с вводом нескольких значений?

Tags: база-данных, mysqli, access

**Используется**
Access 2016
MySql 5,7 - х64

Access использует внешние таблицы через ODBC.
Таблицы расположены на MySql

Как сделать в форме  сценарий для ввода в поле нескольких значений?
Сценарий
1. Набираем с клавиатуры несколько символов меток
2. Access предлагает наиболее подходящие для набранных символов метки из справочника (см. скрин)
3. По средствам стрелок клавиатуры выбираем из списка необходимую позицию.
4. Нажимаем "Ввод".
5. По средствам нажатия "Ввод" позиция заносится в поле. После позиции ставится   знак разделителя. "," (запятая) например.
6. Набираем следующую позицию.
7. Цикл повторяется. См. п.2 - п.6.

**[ССЫЛКА](http://transfiles.ru/v3fa3)** на файл

**Вопрос.**
Как реализовать данный цикл?

Скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вижу проблем с реализацией через событие OnChange - рируем окошко с требуемым списком, анализируя содержимое строки. Кода, будет, правда, не несколько строк.

Comment: @Sergey S. Плохо разбираюсь в VBA. Не могли бы вы на примере приложенного файла показать на, что это будет похоже... Если вам не сложно..